# How to execute sql server query statements in parallel?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pyspark, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario in which there is one activity in my Azure Data Factory Pipeline. This activity copies data from history tables to archive tables. And a history table can have upto 600 million records. There is a SQL Server Stored Procedure(SP) in this activity which executes three child SPs using a while loop:

```
while i<3
    exec proc
    i = i + 1
```

The 3 SPs copy data from history table to archive table in SQL DW. This activity is common to 600 pipelines and different activities copy different number of tables.

But, while loop executes the child SPs one by one.
I tried searching for a way to parallelize the 3 SPs but found nothing in SQL Server.

I want to trigger all the child SPs at once. Is there anyway I can do this? Any solution in SQL Server, Data Factory,Python Script or Spark will suffice.

Comment: You don't, not within the SQL itself anyway; SQL is executed sequentially. If you want 3 statements to be run in parallel, you would need to run 3 parallel threads *outside* SQL itself, in your application, open 3 connections simultaneously, and run the 3 statements/batches.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute 3 child stored procedures parallelly inside a parent stored procedure. But you can execute the 3 child procedures directly without requiring any parent procedure.

Please follow the demonstration below where I executed 3 stored procedures in parallel using azure data factory (For each activity):

- I have 3 stored procedures `sp1, sp2 and sp3` that I want to execute in parallel. I created a parameter (Array) that holds the names of these stored procedures.

[image]

- This parameter acts as `items` value (@pipeline().parameters.sp_names) in `for each` activity. Here, in for each activity, **do not check `sequential` checkbox** and specify batch value as `3`.

[image]

- Now inside the for each activity, create a stored procedure activity and create the necessary linked service. While selecting the stored procedure name check the edit box. Give dynamic content for stored procedure name as `@item()`
  [image]

This procedure helps to run the stored procedures parallelly. Look at the outputs when the same is executed with `For each` activity having **sequential execution** and **batch execution**.

- With Sequential execution:
  [image]
- With Batch execution:

[image]